# Undefined reference to ros::init on Jade

Tags: ros-jade

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm a freshman on ROS. And recently I come up with a problem when I learn the Tutorials(WritingPublisherSubscriber(c++)).

When I add the talker.cpp to the project, It  appear I have problem with Undefined reference

Here is my talker.cpp

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"

#include <sstream>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

   ros::init(argc, argv, "talker");


   return 0;
}
```

The CMakeLists.txt file has following content

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(beginner_tutorials)

## Find catkin and any catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS 
roscpp 
rospy 
std_msgs 
message_generation)

## Declare ROS messages and services
add_message_files(FILES Num.msg)
add_service_files(FILES AddTwoInts.srv)

## Generate added messages and services
generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES std_msgs)

## Declare a catkin package
catkin_package()

## Build talker and listener
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(talker src/talker.cpp)
target_link_libraries(talker ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(talker beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)
```

and Package.xml is here

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
 <name>beginner_tutorials</name>
   <version>0.0.0</version>
 <description>The beginner_tutorials package</description>


  <maintainer email="lizhuo@todo.todo">lizhuo</maintainer>
  <license>TODO</license>

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>

  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
  <run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>rospy</run_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>


</package>
```

While compiling the above code using catkin_make, the error is

```
Base path: /home/lizhuo/catkin_lz
Source space: /home/lizhuo/catkin_lz/src
Build space: /home/lizhuo/catkin_lz/build
Devel space: /home/lizhuo/catkin_lz/devel
Install space: /home/lizhuo/catkin_lz/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/lizhuo/catkin_lz/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/lizhuo/catkin_lz/build"
####
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] [  0%] Built target _beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_check_deps_Num
Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target _beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_check_deps_AddTwoInts
[ 33%] Built target beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_py
[ 50%] [ 66%] Built target beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp
Built target beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_lisp
[ 91%] Built target beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_eus
[ 91%] Linking CXX executable ../devel/lib/beginner_tutorials/talker
Built target beginner_tutorials_generate_messages
CMakeFiles/talker.dir/src/talker.cpp.o：in the function ‘main’：
talker.cpp:(.text+0x55)：对‘ros::init(int&, char**, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,       std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int)’未定义的引用 (it means undefined reference)
collect2: error：ld return 1
beginner_tutorials/CMakeFiles/talker.dir/build.make:102: recipe for target  'devel/lib/beginner_tutorials/talker' failed
make[2]: *** [devel/lib/beginner_tutorials/talker] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1091: recipe for target 'beginner_tutorials/CMakeFiles/talker.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [beginner_tutorials/CMakeFiles/talker.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

I look though many answers, but cannot solve my problem. So I really need help. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241373/undefined-reference-to-ros::init-on-jade/) by [Lizhuo](https://answers.ros.org/users/27711/lizhuo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-08-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lfr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26831/lfr/) on 2016-08-09**:
I don't know if it will work but you can try to write `<ros/ros.h>` instead of `"ros/ros.h"`

**Comment by [Lizhuo](https://answers.ros.org/users/27711/lizhuo/) on 2016-08-09**:
I have try it. But it doesn't work. @Ifr

**Comment by [alecive](https://answers.ros.org/users/27723/alecive/) on 2016-08-10**:
Why do you have your `add_dependencies` after `target_link_libraries`?

**Comment by [Lizhuo](https://answers.ros.org/users/27711/lizhuo/) on 2016-08-10**:
Just follow the tutorial. The problem is discovered, that the version of GCC is changed from 4.9 to 5.
When I switch the version back to 4.9, It works! @alecive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string` in the link error, it looks like your compiler is using the C++11 standard libraries, but most of ROS is usually compiled with the previous version of C++ ( C++98 ).

If you have an environment variable or some other setting that is putting the compiler into C++11 mode, you should disable that.

Usually, the default compiler flags are fine, but you haven't said which operating system you're using or how you installed ROS, so I can't be certain.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lizhuo](https://answers.ros.org/users/27711/lizhuo/) on 2016-08-09**:
my operating system is Ubuntu 15.04 and my GCC version is 5. Could you tell me how to disable C++11? Thank you~@ahendrix

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-08-09**:
It looks like the default compiler for Ubuntu 15.04 is probably GCC 4.9.2. Did you switch to GCC 5?

**Comment by [Lizhuo](https://answers.ros.org/users/27711/lizhuo/) on 2016-08-10**:
Yes. I have switched. But I try to change GCC version back to 4.9, it also doesn't work. @ahendrix

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-08-10**:
"it also doesn't work" is not helpful. Were you not able to switch the compiler back to the default version, or does it still fail to compile with the default compiler? Does it give the same error message or a new error message?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-08-10**:
If you successfully switched back to the default version of gcc, you probably still have the old object files that contain bad references. You probably need to clean your workspace and rebuild. Either run `catkin_make clean` or remove the auto-generated build and devel folders in your workspace.

**Comment by [Lizhuo](https://answers.ros.org/users/27711/lizhuo/) on 2016-08-10**:
Thanks! My problem has solved. First, I switch the GCC version back to 4.9. Then  run CATKIN_MAKE CLEAN to clean the build file. And when I run CATKIN_MAKE this time, it is OK!
Thank you @ahendrix !

**Comment by [Lizhuo](https://answers.ros.org/users/27711/lizhuo/) on 2016-08-10**:
should I close this problem?

**Comment by [tsbertalan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28618/tsbertalan/) on 2017-02-11**:
I still get the `undefined reference to ros::init` after trying these fixes. I've written up my problem in a separate question [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/253557/undefined-reference-to-rosinit-with-beginner_tutorials/). Is there something simple I'm missing that one of you can point out?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-02-11**:
Nope. I saw your other question a few weeks back and didn't have anything to add.